# Maven: package net.jcip.annotations does not exist

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to use @net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe in my Java code. I have tried to import it is a dependency in the pom.xml for the project as of below. However, I still get the error: Is something wrong with my import?

**package net.jcip.annotations does not exist**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        {...}
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Where does this error appear, and what IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. It appears both when I compile in IntelliJ (Ctrl + F9), and when I run the maven goal "test".

Comment: Is the `net.jcip` Maven import working, or are some things in red?

Comment: I declare the full "@net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe" and it is only "NotThreadSafe" which displays as red.

Comment: I just tried this in my IntelliJ project and it works without problems.  Are you placing the @NotThreadSafe annotation on a _class_ or a _method_?  It is designed to be placed on a _class_.  Placing it on a method will prompt IntelliJ to turn it red.

Comment: Also, when I Ctrl + Click on @NotThreadSafe, IntelliJ displays the NotThreadSafe.class in the correct package (package net.jcip.annotations;). Still, when I compile, I get the error "package net.jcip.annotations does not exist"

Comment: It is placed on a (test) class.

Comment: `SHIFT + CTRL + ALT + S` Do you see jcip-annotations:1.0 listed there?

Comment: Where do you mean? Under "Modules" or "Libraries"?

Comment: I meant Modules but since we know what the problem was, let's not discuss further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do it like the above you only add the dependency to the classpath of the maven-surefire-plugin which is not what you intend. You have to give it in your pom like this:

```xml
<project...>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Furthermore given the dependency to surefire-juni47 is not necessary, cause surefire plugin handles this on it's own. So this can look like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
        {...}
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```